# get value from external webpage (php or java)

Tags: java, php

I need to get a number from a external webpage

```
<span>
<b>Maximum price:</b>
7 //value i need
</span>
```

Then display said number

Comment: You're going to have to give us some more details, here.  Do you want to write a script in PHP or Java which will fetch a web site over HTTP and extract a certain portion of it?  Or what?

Comment: Please edit your post and expand more.

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can use HTMLUnit library. It's good at HTML extraction.
For example something similar to:

```
webClient=new WebClient();
HtmlPage page=webClient.getPage(url);
for(HtmlElement elem:page.getElementsByTagName("span")) {
   //And then getChildren(), getText ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code works. I've used this thread as the source page.

```
<?php

// Read the whole file.
$lines = file('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573498/get-value-from-external-webpage-php-or-java');

// Go through every line ..
while ($line = array_shift($lines)) {

        // Stop when you find the label we're looking for.
        if (strpos($line, 'Maximum price') !== false) break;

}

// The next line has your value on it.
$line = array_shift($lines);

// Print the first word on the line.
$values = explode(' ', $line);
echo $values[0];
```

Comment: The split function is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I replaced it with an equivalent explode() call.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the address of the page and you are sure that their content will not change during the time, you can find the **number** by means of DOM. But I need more detail about your problem.

Comment: http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/viewitem.ws?obj=1040  Im trying to get the min man and market price values.

Comment: At first download the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/ then you can use its examples here: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ If you need more help please let me know.

Comment: // Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';